# Issue in sqlite with "like" in android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

In `sqlite` don't have the operator [ ] for like.

*For example*,

`select * from user where name LIKE '%[abch]%';`

this work is all the others `sqlserver`,`oracle` but **not** in `sqlite`.

Someone know an alternative in `sqlite` for this?

I am working with android.

I think I **can't** use **regexp** because I am using **android**.

Answer (score 1):

sqlite only supports a small subset of regular sql. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

See [Query Android's SQLiteDatabase using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549449/query-androids-sqlitedatabase-using-regex) about using regex on Android.

Short answer, dont bother. You can use `like` for the basics and anything else you really shouldn't be using regex for.

You can always do this

`select * from user 
where name LIKE '%a%'
or name LIKE '%b%'
or name LIKE '%c%'
or name LIKE '%h%'
;`

Comment: the problem is i put a simple example but i need sometings like thiselect * from user where name LIKE '%[abc2][def3][fha][klm]%' and more big that it

Comment: How many rows are you scanning and why? You might want to consider either looking into installing a regexp function or if you set is small enough you can do it in java. Alternatively you can restructure your tables and avoid this issue all together

Comment: i am using the bd of contacts in android i can't restructure this bd

Comment: i what to do a filter to users using the buttons of a dial like the phonebook of samsung